# Как вытащить слова, начиная с 10 символа?

Tags: php

1. имеются 100 файлов.
2. каждое название файла состоит из "названиеНужнаяМнеСтрокаИЛишнее" (названия у всех одинаковое).
   Вопрос:
   Как мне добавить все эти файлы(названия) в массив, и каким образом вывести нужные мне символы с этого списка?

Comment: _вытащить слова, начиная с 10 символа?_ - и до конца строки? Или какое-то количество символов, начиная с десятого?

Comment: с 10 до 20, как пример.

Comment: `echo mb_substr($string, 9, 10);`

Comment: а как всю папку(содержимое) добавить в массив?

Comment: ну прочитайте эту папку, например функцией glob().

Comment: Или через scandir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filenames = scandir ($your_directory);
$names = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
    $names[] = substr($filename, 10, 5); // c 10ого символа взять 5 символов
```

Comment: работает!) спасибо! Возможно с глобом тоже можно было бы, да я новичок в php, и у меня не сработало..